# Fsutil usn queryJournal works on root (f:) volume but not on the child folders - Access denied

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2016, fsutil

On windows server 2016 trying to execute

**fsutil usn queryJournal f:\demo**

but keep getting

**Error: Access denied**

However same command agains root volume f:

**fsutil usn queryJournal f:**

returns data successfully.
I'm running it from Administrative terminal.
Added access to the f: to Everyone but no luck
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Most commands (and in particular queryJounal) work on a volume not a folder.

> **Syntax**
> fsutil usn [createjournal] m=<maxsize> a=<allocationdelta> <volumepath>
> fsutil usn [deletejournal] {/d | /n} <volumepath>
> fsutil usn [enablerangetracking] <volumepath> [options]
> fsutil usn [enumdata] <fileref> <lowUSN> <highUSN> <volumepath>
> fsutil usn [queryjournal] <volumepath>
> fsutil usn [readdata] <filename>
> fsutil usn [readjournal] [c= <chunk-size> s=<file-size-threshold>] <volumepath>\

From [learn.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-usn)